# How to fix Android studio Unable to load class 'org.gradle.initialization.BuildCancellationToken' error

Tags: android, android-studio, dependencies, load

I installed the latest hedgehog version where there is an issue with sync option. Can someone give a detailed description of how to fix the error?

```
Unable to load class 'org.gradle.initialization.BuildCancellationToken'
org.gradle.initialization.BuildCancellationToken

Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)

Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.

Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)
Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.

In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.
```

I tried uninstalling reinstalling and changing some factors with the build->gradle tools according to YouTube tutorials. But it didn't work.
gradle properties-

```
{# Project-wide Gradle settings.
# IDE (e.g. Android Studio) users:
# Gradle settings configured through the IDE *will override*
# any settings specified in this file.
# For more details on how to configure your build environment visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html
# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
# When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
# This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:decoupled_projects
# org.gradle.parallel=true
# AndroidX package structure to make it clearer which packages are bundled with the
# Android operating system, and which are packaged with your app's APK
# https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/androidx-rn
android.useAndroidX=true
# Kotlin code style for this project: "official" or "obsolete":
kotlin.code.style=official
# Enables namespacing of each library's R class so that its R class includes only the
# resources declared in the library itself and none from the library's dependencies,
# thereby reducing the size of the R class for that library
android.nonTransitiveRClass=true}

gradle-wrapper.properties

distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.2-bin.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

local.properties

```
## This file is automatically generated by Android Studio.
# Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!
#
# This file should *NOT* be checked into Version Control Systems,
# as it contains information specific to your local configuration.
#
# Location of the SDK. This is only used by Gradle.
# For customization when using a Version Control System, please read the
# header note.
sdk.dir=C\:\\Users\\Home\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk
```

settings.gradle.kts

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.name = "Mydew"
include(":app")
```

Comment: There could be version issue of the gradle or java and may be kotlin version. So please share your grade so it could be traced.

Comment: As stack doesn't allow to share files I updated the files in the question.Can you please check it?